# Which JSR 168 compatible Java web frameworks are there?

Tags: java, frameworks, portlet, jsr168

There are many Java web application frameworks available but what are my alternatives when developing JSR 168 portlets? I found a couple:

- [Struts](http://portals.apache.org/bridges/bridges-struts/index.html)
- [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/portlet.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's it Sven, I haven't tried JSF portlet bridge, but I have been working with Struts portlet bridge and spring-webmvc-portlet almost 2 years.

this is **my own** opinion :

I would try to avoid using Struts portlet bridge. It's a dead thing that still exists because some Portals had utilized it and it is still built in them. It's quite old, it serves its purpose, but with something like spring-webmvc-portlet - using it wouldn't be wise. Unless you are Struts enthusiast and you haven't tried Spring-mvc or JSF.

I like the principle how spring portlet environment is integrated into servlet env. There is also everyhing that developer needs already implemented, except few things like

- [Add multipart request support to portlet resource requests (SPR-7662)](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7662)
- [Spring Portlet MVC - Unable to return JSON data from @ResourceMapping (SPR-7344)](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7344)

With Struts bridge you end up doing tons of low level stuff to hide the fact, that after request hits the Main Portal Servlet, it becomes "portlet request". With Spring you don't care :-) Talking about portals like Liferay, JBoss or uPortal

Answer (score 0):

JSF with a portlet bridge: http://jboss.org/portletbridge